# Authenticating remotely validated user credentials for TYPO3 backend

Tags: php, authentication, typo3, typo3-8.x

I need a bit help in login in a backend user whos credentials have been verified by a remote server. The actual user and all its permissions are set in TYPO3, but the password is stored on a remote server.

So far I've created a small extension, that redirects the backend login to my Login provider:

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXTCONF']['backend']['loginProviders'][1433416747]['provider'] = \User\MyExtension\Hooks\LoginProvider::class;
```

where I check the username and password combination on the remote server.

```
class LoginProvider implements LoginProviderInterface
{
    public function render(StandaloneView $view, PageRenderer $pageRenderer, LoginController $loginController)
    {

        $view->setTemplatePathAndFilename(GeneralUtility::getFileAbsFileName('EXT:my_extension/Resources/Private/Templates/BELogin.html'));

        // Check request
        if (
            isset($_POST['login_status'])
            && $_POST['login_status'] == 'login'
            && !empty($_POST['username'])
            && !empty($_POST['p_field'])
            && $_POST['interface'] == 'backend'
        ) {
            // Get EXT connection data from settings
            $EXT_CONFIG       = unserialize($GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXT']['extConf']['my_extension']);
            $this->extServer = $EXT_CONFIG['extServer'];
            $this->extDC     = $EXT_CONFIG['extDC'];

            // Assign received login data
            $this->username = GeneralUtility::_GP('username');
            $this->password = GeneralUtility::_GP('p_field');

            // Try to authenticate
            if ($this->checkCredentials()) {
                // @TODO: Need to log in the verified user credentials!
            }
        }
    }

    private function checkCredentials()
    {
        // Check if local user exists
        $local = $GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->exec_SELECTcountRows("uid", "be_users", "username='{$this->username}' AND disable=0") ?? 0;

        // Check credentials and recieve user object if correct, or false if wrong
        if ($local > 0) {
            $ext           = new EXT($this->extServer, $this->extDC);
            $this->extUser = $ext->authorize($this->username, $this->password);
        }

        return $this->extUser ? true : false;
    }
}
```

**Now I would need to log in the verified user, but can't understand how.**

PS: I already found `BackendUserAuthentication`, but that only works once the user is already authenticated (or I don't know how to use).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `LoginProvider` is only for rendering a different login form (e.g. for openID, which does not need a password field).

You need to implement an authentication service: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/Typo3ServicesReference/Authentication/Index.html

Comment: Can you add a small example on how do I redirect to my Authentication service?

Comment: If you only want to authenticate a username/password against another authentication service there is no need for a "redirect" mechanism. You create an authentication service - and it should internally perform the authentication against your service and only report 0/100/200 to TYPO3. Have a look at the existing authentication services:

Comment: typo3/sysext/rsaauth/ext_localconf.php:
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addService(

Comment: @kraftb Ok, I added that to my config, and it does call my AuthService on submit, but the service in the rsa example has only `init` and `processLogin` in it. Now the original class `AuthenticationService` has an `authUser` method, that returns 200 on success, but I cant seem to understand, how to implement it. The `init` method **is** called on the submit, but others are not. I understand, that I might sound silly and am probably looking from a wrong perspective at this >.<